Html Canvas Not updating/animating for some reason (html/Javascript) (error in code i think)
Somewhere around here...........
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

width = canvas.width
height = canvas.height


var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

centerX= width/2
centerY = height/2


var rot = 0

function rotation(){
    rot += 0.1
}



function drawBackground(){
    const circlegrad = c.createRadialGradient(centerX, centerY, 40,centerX,centerY, 60)
    circlegrad.addColorStop(0,"black");
    circlegrad.addColorStop(1,"white");
    c.beginPath
    c.fillStyle = circlegrad
    c.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)
    c.stroke()
}

drawBackground();


function Spiral(gap, steps, angle, way ){
    this.gap = gap;
    this.steps = steps;
    this.increment = 3*Math.PI/this.steps;
    this.theta = this.increment
    this.angle = angle
    this.way = way

    this.draw = function() {
        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(centerX, centerY)
        if (way == 1){
            while(this.theta < 60*Math.PI) {
                this.newX = centerX + this.theta * (Math.cos(this.theta + this.angle)) * (this.gap + Math.pow(7/6, (this.theta/2)))/10; 
                this.newY = centerY + this.theta * (Math.sin(this.theta + this.angle)) * (this.gap + Math.pow(7/6, (this.theta/2)))/10; 
                c.lineTo(this.newX, this.newY);
                this.theta = this.theta + this.increment;
                }
            c.strokeStyle = "black"
            c.stroke()
        } else if (way == 2) {
            while(this.theta < 10*Math.PI) {
                this.newX = centerX + this.theta * (Math.sin(this.theta + this.angle)) * (this.gap + Math.pow(5/4, (this.theta *20))); 
                this.newY = centerY + this.theta * (Math.cos(this.theta + this.angle)) * (this.gap + Math.pow(5/4, (this.theta *20))); 
                c.lineTo(this.newX, this.newY);
                this.theta = this.theta + this.increment;
                }
            c.strokeStyle = "black"
            c.stroke()
        }

    }

    this.update = function(){
        c.clearRect(0, 0 , width, height)
        this.angle += 10/9
        this.draw();
    }
    
}




var spiralArray = []


for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    spiralArray.push(new Spiral(1.1, 70, 45 * i, 1));
}
for(var i = 0; i < 71; i++){
    spiralArray.push(new Spiral(1.1, 190, 10 * i, 2));
}

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (){
    console.log('spin')
    for (var i = 0; i < spiralArray.length; i++){
        spiralArray[i].update();
    }
})



// function animate(){
//     requestAnimationFrame(animate)
//     c.clearRect(0, 0 , width, height)
//     for (var i = 0; i < spiralArray.length; i++){
//         spiralArray[i].update();
//         spiralArray[i].draw();
//     }
    
//     console.log("Update")

    
    
// }

// animate();


I removed the animate function to try to see if the problem was elsewhere... i dont see it. i am calling .draw() after the update yet it seems that the values i change in the update function do not get used in the draw function. and the spirals i created do not spin but stay in one place. Not sure what to do anymore. Tried everything within my skill range and am seeking help here now, far too tired to keep debugging this atm.

In each and every of your Spiral items's .update() method, you do clear the whole canvas, so only the last item gets painted. You want to do this only once, in the animate function (and you might want to add a drawBackground() right after)
